# Is the function with return or without better in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new at coding and I am currently learning about the return statement. consequently I am coded two functions, one **without** the **return** tool and one **with** the **return** statement whereby the two functions are doing the same thing. The functions are calculating after users input the price for the route. For my programming development I want to now which of these functions are better to use, the function with return or the function without. Thank you.

```
function calculatingExpenses() {
  let km = prompt("How far is your target");
  let partialExpenses = 1.65;
  const wholeExpenses = km *= partialExpenses;
  console.log(wholeExpenses);
}
```

```
function wholeFunction() {
    function calculatingExpenses(km) {
      return km * 1.65;
    }
    const km = prompt("How far is your target?");
    const wholeExpenses = calculatingExpenses(km);
    console.log(wholeExpenses);
}
```

Comment: You mean a function within a function? That depends. But a `return` is always a good idea.

Comment: They're basically the same. `return` is not a "method", it's a *statement*. If you don't have a `return`, a caller of the function will always get back `undefined`.

Comment: Yes. What does it depends on in generally?

Comment: If the function doesn't need to return anything, there's no point in having a `return` statement.

Comment: There's little point in creating the nested function if you're only going to call it once.

Comment: Ok. When do I need to return something or what does it mean to return something specifically respectively?

Comment: You need a return statement in the inner function, because the caller is assigning the result to a variable.

Comment: You can also return a function, or pass a function as parameter. Actually it's very common and useful

Comment: So to store for example the users input and us it thereafter?

Answer (score 0):

Both work just fine, although technically your first function is slightly more optimized because your second function entails adding an additional function call frame to the call stack making it ever so slightly slower.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to limit each function to one responsibility.

Also, try to make the functions without side effects.

I would re-write your code like this: (but this is becoming an opinionated question/answer)

```js
function calculatingExpenses(km) {
  return km * 1.65;
}

function main() {
  let km = prompt("How far is your target");
  let result = calculatingExpenses(km)
  console.log(result);
}

main();
```